# Chef: How to test that a node attribute is not stored on Chef Server?

Tags: rspec, chef-infra, recipe, chefspec

After some chef zero runs (which save the node state as local .json files) I was dismayed to find this in the node files:

    `...
    "ssmtp": {
      "auth_username": "secret user name",
      "auth_password": "even-more-secret password"
    }`

The same runs on Chef Server would save the node data on the server. That's is a problem of course, and I'll have to replace credentials, modify the recipes, etc.  I am still investigating what caused this in the first place but my question is:

**How I can create an rspec/chefspec test for a recipe to verify that a particular node attribute is NOT saved persistently in the node's .json file or on Chef Server?**

I'd like to add this to my specs to make sure it never happens again.

### Epilogue

**The big lesson here is that anything finding its way into any node attribute winds up being saved in the node object representation.**

Comment: Per Chef node docs: "A normal attribute is a setting that persists in the node object. A normal attribute has a higher attribute precedence than a default attribute."  so perhaps my question is "how can I test if a node attribute is a **normal** attribute?

Comment: You could also try to suppress the saving of this node attribute to the chef server. See: https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/blacklist_node_attrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chef Server will save all attributes, even if they are normal or default or another precedence level. You can get around this by using [node.run_state](https://docs.chef.io/recipes.html#node-run-state) which can be used to "stash transient data during a chef-client run."

You can see this at work in the [elkstack](https://github.com/rackspace-cookbooks/elkstack) community cookbook, most notably in the [_lumberjack_secrets.rb](https://github.com/rackspace-cookbooks/elkstack/blob/master/recipes/_lumberjack_secrets.rb) recipe.

`node.run_state` being set:

```
if <CONDITION ABBREVIATED>
  node.run_state['lumberjack_decoded_key'] = Base64.decode64(lumberjack_secrets['key'])
  ....
end
```

`node.run_state` being used:

```
lumberjack_keypair = node.run_state['lumberjack_decoded_key'] && node.run_state['lumberjack_decoded_certificate']
```

As for the test, I haven't "tested" this myself, but you would be testing to make sure the attribute is not set, like this:

```
it 'should not have secret attributes set' do
  node = chef_run.node
  expect (node['my_secret']).to be_nil
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. (Fog lifted)

Comment: So at a high level it is impossible to use node attributes to set up ssmtp (using the standard cookbook) without the credentials winding up in the stored node object.

I'm accepting this: "Chef Server will save all attributes, even if they are normal or default or another precedence level."  as the actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

The key is in the comment from the Chef docs, *"A normal attribute is a setting that persists in the node object. A normal attribute has a higher attribute precedence than a default attribute."*  That breaks the problem down into testing if an attribute is a "normal" attribute.

Digging into the Chef::Node and Chef::Node::Attribute class code, I found you can call `node.attributes.normal` to get just the the normal attributes.  So this concise test correctly fails, indicating that my secret info *is* going to be stored persistently in the node object!

`it 'does not have a normal attribute node[ssmtp][auth_password]' do
    expect(subject.node.attributes.normal['ssmtp'].keys).to_not include 'auth_password'
  end`

resulting in this decent error message:

`Failure/Error: expect(subject.node.attributes.normal['ssmtp'].keys).to_not include 'auth_password'
       expected ["auth_username", "auth_password"] not to include "auth_password"`

You could also test to that if a specific value is not set, but I think testing that the key does not exist is more to the point.

*Somehow I always get new insights from simply formulating a question to post here.  So it goes.*

Comment: Rats.  @MattBarlow is right.  My "solution" only moved the problem to another part of the node object representation.  Now it's with the default attributes, not the normal attributes.  D'oh

Comment: Worth noting `node.normal['attribute']` will give the same behavior. (access by `normal` method of `node`instead of accessing hash by method, you should never mix method and string access `node['attributes']['normal']['ssmtp'].keys` would have the effect with a clearest meaning of what is what.